# CSS with multiple blank Links added

Tags: html, css

I am a complete newbie on CSS and going through some examples on Youtube using HTML and CSS.
My problem is that multiple blank Links appear. (Here is a link to let you know what i mean. http://cly.site90.net/images/Error.png.)

The HTML is straightforward:

```
<body>
<div id="divWall">
 <div id="divLinks">
    <div id="divNav">
       <ul>
           <li><a href="Index.html">Main</li>
           <li><a href="About.html">About</li>
           <li><a href="Log-in.html">Log-in</li>
           <li><a href="Register.html">Register</li>
       </ul/
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
 body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, div, ul, li {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }
 body{
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, asns-serif;
 background-color: #FFF;
 }
 #divWall {
 width:700px;
 margin:20px auto;
 }
 #divLinks {
   width:700px;
   background:#666;
 }
 #divNav {
  width:384px;
  background:#666;
  height:36px;
  margin:0 auto;
 }
 #divNav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
 }
 #divNav ul li {
   float:left;
 }
 #divNav ul li a {
   display:block;
   height:20px;
   background:#000;
   width:80px;
   font-size:0.8em;
   color:#FFF;
   text-align:center;
   text-decoration:none;
   margin:7px;
 }
```

The 3 blank links have no writing, will link to Index, About & Log-in.html. When I take out `height:20px;` or `display:block;` from `#divNav ul li a{}` they will disappear http://cly.site90.net/images/Error1.png. but I cant re-size the links at all (and i really would like to).

I would like to know where these extra Links came from and hopefully a solution?
Just remember I am new to CSS and any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you for you time.

Comment: What does you question-title mean? multi-What?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to close your `<a>` tags:

Change:

```
<li><a href="Index.html">Main</li>
```

To:

```
<li><a href="Index.html">Main</a></li>
```

---

You also need to fix a typo:

Change:

```
</ul/
```

To:

```
</ul>
```

---

[**SEE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/EgR3U/)

Comment: Wow, I didn't even notice the `<a>`s not being closed 0.0. Good catch =p.

Comment: @Kyomu: A proper IDE would have caught this easily :)

Comment: Thank you cant believe i miss it cheers:)

Comment: @JjDelaney No problem, please mark as answer if this has helped

Answer (score 0):

Your  tags are not closed, you need `</a>` after the text,

For example...

```
<li><a href="Index.html">Main</a></li>
```

Your end UL tag also has a typo in, you've wrote `</ul/` when it should be `</ul>`.

Im not sure if these will fix your problem though but html & css can be strange like that! :)